# Подлежащее в предложении "Это было глубочайшее проникновение в прошлое"

Tags: синтаксический-разбор, подлежащее

Является ли слово "это" подлежащим в предложении?

**Это было глубочайшее проникновение в прошлое.**

Answer (score 3):

Является ли слово "это" подлежащим в предложении: *Это было глубочайшее проникновение в прошлое?*

Да, ***это*** в данном предложении — подлежащее.

А сказуемое — ***было проникновение.***